# How to fix the length of a line in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, line

As you all know kivy Line take points with `(x1,y1.x2,y2,x3,y3)`. I want to create a geometric compass like it is in [here](https://www.mathspad.co.uk/i2/construct.php). Considering the compass here I created a basic framework of this, which doesn't seems to be good enough.. (though isn't even close to match the compass there but is just the basic idea)

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.widget import Canvas
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard

class Main(FloatLayout):


    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)



        self.my_widget = Widget(size_hint= (0.6,0.6),pos_hint = {'x':0.5,'top' : 0.8})
        self.add_widget(self.my_widget)

        with self.my_widget.canvas:
            Color(rgba = (0,0,0,1))

        def on_touch_downah(self,touch):

            self.line = Line(points = (touch.x,touch.y),width = 4)
            self.canvas.add(self.line)

        def on_touch_moveah(self,touch):
            self.line.points += touch.x,touch.y

        self.my_widget.bind(on_touch_down=on_touch_downah)
        self.my_widget.bind(on_touch_move=on_touch_moveah)

        def on_touch_downeh(self, touch):
            self.x_ = touch.x
            self.y_ = touch.y
            self.lines = Line(points=(touch.x,touch.y),width = 5)
            self.canvas.add(self.lines)

        def on_touch_moveeh(self, touch):
            self.x2 = self.x_ + 0.1
            self.y2 = self.y_ + 0.1
            self.lines.points = (self.x_,self.y_,touch.x,touch.y,touch.x,touch.y)

        self.my_widget.bind(on_touch_down=on_touch_downeh)
        self.my_widget.bind(on_touch_move=on_touch_moveeh)


class Mysapp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

Mysapp().run()
```

It is just a framework but the only problem here is the length of the straight _line is not getting fixed, meaning it keep changing because of `x3,y3`. Is there any way to fix the length of this line so that under no circumstances its length would get modified but it should still be able to change its position?

Or is there any better widget for this purpose other than the circle widget? I want the user to be able to create curves and arcs as well as circles therefore can't switch to circle widget. The user should be able to use it just as the geometric compass as you can see the provided link..

Comment: I don't understand the question - you want to change the line's points but not change its length? Can you explain exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Brother I actually wanted to create a geometric compass to create circles,arcs,curves etc. the problem here is there is no good widget to work with . So i came across the provided code which basically have two lines.

Comment: One is a `straight line ` and other is a `free-hand line `. so that i can draw a curve,arc or circle. keeping the distance of straight line same this can be achieved. here the advantage is if we can maintain the length of the straight line and can change its positon (Which i want to achieve) then the free-hand line can draw a perfect circle or curve that i want .. So the thing is I want to fix the length of the Line at the same time can change the position of the Line

Comment: If I understand right, you should use the touch position to calculate the angle of the point you care about relative to the point you want to move around, and draw a line of fixed length in that direction.

Comment: How can this be achieved?